# Is it possible to create a library using Flutter to be used in a native iOS app?

Tags: swift, flutter

I was wondering if it would be possible for a library to be created in Flutter and then have it be exported (as a .xcframework) to have it be imported and used in Xcode? I am a beginner in Flutter and don't know much about Xcode and Swift.

For instance I create a library file in Flutter called my_test.dart which has a class and a basic function, such as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestClass {
  void printTestString(){
    print("Test String");
  }
}
```

I would then convert this into a .xcframework which I will then attach/embed to my Xcode project and use TestClass.printTestString() inside one of the Swift files.

I tried running 'flutter build ios-framework' and it made App.xcframework and Flutter.xcframework, however when those were imported into Xcode, I cannot access the function I created in Flutter prior to building it.

I also tried researching other Flutter templates such as plugin and module to see if they work since tutorials related to this topic have different answers and honestly I'm wondering if it was actually possible. If it is possible can someone direct me to a guide where I can follow a procedure?

Thank you very much.

Comment: yes this is possible

Comment: It is possible to create Dynamic Framework using flutter. Using Cocoapods you can embed flutter developed frameworks into iOS Native Project.